# How to understand CPU and memory consumption in xcode debug

Tags: ios, xcode, cpu-usage

In Xcode 5, there's a new debug panel that shows the CPU and memory consumption in % and MB respectively. How do we make use of this? Is there a CPU % threshold I should try to stay below? I sometimes see my apps goes to 100% or over.. does that mean I am doing too much processing in my app and should try to optimize?

Any tips?

[image]

(PS. I'm developing on iOS)

Comment: as for ram It's impossible to give you an exact number, but anything less than 25mb should be fine.

Comment: I understand what the numbers means, but how to interpret them is the question.. is 50% CPU usage good, bad, or ugly?

Answer (score 0):

A modern iPhone or iPad has 1024Mb memory.
But how much of that is available for apps is something that Apple has never divulged.
Just use as little memory as possible, and release non essential memory when the OS notifies your app about low memory.

Similarly, use as little CPU as possible, but more importantly, do not block the UI thread.
Use the profiler to find hot spots for CPU use and try to optimize those.