# Ideal memory usage amounts for iOS apps

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, memory-management

What ranges could be considered Low, Medium, and High in memory usage?

As my app becomes more complex, I notice this number getting higher. I've been trying to use this number as an indicator to how efficiently I'm coding but I've realized I have no bar to compare it with.

[How to understand Memory Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20725235/how-to-understand-cpu-and-memory-consumption-in-xcode-debug) says 1024 Mb to an iPhone/iPad, but obviously all of this memory can't go to the app.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could get(a pretty nice) overview from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15200855/1472337) question. It won't show you low-medium values, but if you know the limit you can adjust below limit.

If you are near the limits in some view - override didReceiveMemoryWarning and dispose resources accordingly.

My advise is to test always on device, as simulator need a lot memory just because of it's architecture and it's not relative to real devices.

Comment: perfect. so seems 640Mb is the crash threshold for most modern Apple iOS devices. exactly the bar I needed ty

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the simulator. Its memory usage does look scary compared to real devices :)